# Example of a Noetherian domain which is not equidimensional

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, integral-domain

A finite dimensional commutative ring $R$ with unity is called *equidimensional* if all its minimal prime ideals have same dimension (dimension of a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ is defined to be Krull dimension of the ring $R/\mathfrak p$) and every maximal ideal has the height same as dimension of the ring.

I want to have an example of a Noetherian domain which is not equidimensional.

Note that $R$ cannot be a finite type $k$ algebra, neither it can be local.

Thank you.

Comment: "An easy counterexample: consider the polynomial ring B=k[x,y] with coefficients in a field k, let m be a maximal ideal and p a prime ideal of height 1 not contained in m and localize B at the multiplicative subset B∖(m∪p). The ring obtained this way is semi-local, one maximal ideal is generated by m (so has height 2), the other one is generated by p and has height 1."

Comment: Btw, people uses to distinguish among the two properties calling a ring equidimensional if it satisfies the first property, and equicodimensional if it satisfies the second property.

Comment: @user26857 Ok but this is the definition given in Eisenbud.